# JQuery ready infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, preloader

I'm trying to preload images and as soon as they are fully loaded they shall be faded in smoothly (using JQuery). While loading a small loading animation is displayed. For this I tried to create an invisible image tag and let them load there. As soon as they have finished loading i tried to set the source of the original img-tag back to the original.

However I don't find my error for several hours now and have no clue. It seems that it ends up in an infinite loop and then creating the "preload-img-tags" again and again and again.

my HTML:

```
<img src="someimg.jpg" id="img2load" class="preload_img" style="max-width:400px; max-height:400px;">
```

my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var objs = document.getElementsByClassName("preload_img");

for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {

    objs[i].setAttribute("restoreImgPath", objs[i].src);

    //create div for preloading
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", objs[i].src);
    img.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; display:none;");
    img.setAttribute("preloadForId", objs[i].id);
    img.setAttribute("id", "preload_" + objs[i].id);
    document.body.appendChild(img);

    //display loading gif
    objs[i].setAttribute("src", "loading.gif");

   //restore image [... not yet implemented ...]

}
});
```

Thanks in advance. I'm not very experienced in JS yet so please be patient with me 0:-)

Comment: Why include jQuery if you're not going to use it?

Comment: document.ready() and I will need it later.

Comment: Are you sure this piece of code is causing the issue? one place it could happen is if you attach the same class name to the element being added in the loop (Which you are not doing here), because `objs` is a live collection and it gets updated as you add items with the same class again. However for the safer side do `var i = 0, l = objs.length; i < l; i++`

Comment: Yes but you can always use jquery, your script could be reduced to 5 lines of code.

Comment: Feel free to post any "improvements". I'd appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this looks like the problem:

```
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

You keep adding new images. It looks like you are somehow copying over the class names, as well, so `objs.length` keeps getting bigger, and your loop is infinite.  Do this instead:

```
var starting_length = objs.length;
for (var i = 0; i < starting_length; i++) {
    ....
```

Comment: Yes, but the added images don't have the `preload_img` class, don't they ?

Comment: so `document.getElementsByClassName("preload_img")` returns some kind of reference with all elements with this class? Or why is the length increasing after selecting the elements?

thanks for the answer!

Comment: yes `document.getElementsByClassName` creats a live list that will update with the dom